# XmlHttpRequest cannot load ajax call url. Origin domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, callback, xmlhttprequest

I have two ajax call back function in my web page. There is a problem as you can see in the title. Here is my codes:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://....com/Ap.aspx/GetPriceList",
            data: "{categoryId:" + categoryId + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var priceList = JSON.parse(data.d);
                $(function () {
                    $("#slider-range").slider({
                        range: true,
                        min: priceList[0],
                        max: priceList[1],
                        values: [priceList[0], priceList[1]],
                        slide: function (event, ui) {
                            $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " (TL)" + " - " + ui.values[1] + " (TL)");
                        },
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            //                    alert(ui.values[0]);
                            //                    alert(ui.values[1]);
                        }
                    });
                    $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " (TL)" + " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + " (TL)");
                    $("#" + "<%=lblProductCount.ClientID %>").text("Listelenen ürün sayısı :" + priceList[2]);
                    var btnLoadMore = ' <input type="button" alt="Daha Fazla Ürün Yüklemek İçin Buraya Tıklayın" class="moreProduct" onclick="LoadMore();"/>';
                    $("#load").html(btnLoadMore);

                });
            }
        });
```

I see this error in chrome developer's tools. `XMLHtttpRequest cannot load`url`. Origin domain name is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` I also try to write `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` on my master page's page load event. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The server hosting GetPriceList needs to respond to your request with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. You sending it from the client does nothing.